# Scattergeo of Earthquake jsondata using plotly in python

Tags: python, plotly, data-analysis

I would like to visualize the earthquake occurring region on a world map using Plotly. I want to do so by accessing the longitude and latitude to provide a description of the approximate location on the world map.
I also want to see where the most significant earthquakes occurring in the world, I tried to do so by changing the size of markers depending on the magnitude to show the severity of an earthquake.

I don't want to have the pandas module now because I haven't learned them. I have no idea what's wrong with the code, it's showing blank on the browser. I'm at the beginner stage so please suggest me as simple as possible.

Code:

```html
import json
from plotly.graph_objs import Scattergeo, Layout
from plotly import offline

# Explore the structure of the data.
filename = 'Datasets/eq_data_30_day_m1.json'
with open(filename) as f:
    all_eq_data = json.load(f)

# Extracting all the important key features.
all_eq_dicts = all_eq_data['features']

# Extracting the magnitude and the locations.
mags, lons, lats, hover_texts = [], [], [], []
for eq_dict in all_eq_dicts:
    mag = eq_dict['properties']['mag']
    lon = eq_dict['geometry']['coordinates'][0]
    lat = eq_dict['geometry']['coordinates'][1]
    title = eq_dict['properties']['title']
    mags.append(mag)
    lons.append(lon)
    lats.append(lat)
    hover_texts.append(title)

# Map the earthquakes.
data = [{
    'type': 'scattergeo',
    'lon': lons,
    'lat': lats,
    'text': hover_texts,
    'marker': {
        'size': [5*mag for mag in mags],
        'color': mags,
        'colorscale': 'Viridis',
        'reversescale': True,
        'colorbar': {'title': 'Magnitude'},
    },
}]

my_layout = Layout(title='Global Earthquakes')

fig = {'data': data, 'layout': my_layout}
offline.plot(fig, filename='global_earthquakes.html')
```

Comment: Sorry for all the trouble, this is actually my first question here and thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

- **pandas** / **geopandas** removes need to *parse* GEOJSON
- used your code for equivalent without using **pandas**

  1. set following to size markers `"sizeref": 0.02025, "symbol": "circle", "sizemode": "area",`
  2. changed layout to set margins to zero
- found the data is available here https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/geojson.php  No need to download and open files.  just use **requests**

```
import requests
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

res = requests.get("https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/1.0_hour.geojson")

geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(res.json())
px.scatter_geo(
    geo_df,
    lat=geo_df.geometry.y,
    lon=geo_df.geometry.x,
    size="mag",
    color="mag",
    hover_name="place",
)
```

#### without using geopandas

```
import json, requests
from plotly.graph_objs import Scattergeo, Layout
from plotly import offline
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Explore the structure of the data.
# filename = 'Datasets/eq_data_30_day_m1.json'
# with open(filename) as f:
#     all_eq_data = json.load(f)
all_eq_data = requests.get(
    "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/1.0_month.geojson"
).json()

# Extracting all the important key features.
all_eq_dicts = all_eq_data["features"]

# Extracting the magnitude and the locations.
mags, lons, lats, hover_texts = [], [], [], []
for eq_dict in all_eq_dicts:
    mag = eq_dict["properties"]["mag"]
    lon = eq_dict["geometry"]["coordinates"][0]
    lat = eq_dict["geometry"]["coordinates"][1]
    title = eq_dict["properties"]["title"]
    mags.append(mag)
    lons.append(lon)
    lats.append(lat)
    hover_texts.append(title)

# Map the earthquakes.
data = [
    {
        "type": "scattergeo",
        "lon": lons,
        "lat": lats,
        "text": hover_texts,
        "marker": {
            "size": mags,
            "sizeref": 0.02025,
            "symbol": "circle",
            "sizemode": "area",
            "color": mags,
            "colorscale": "Viridis",
            "reversescale": True,
            "colorbar": {"title": "Magnitude"},
        },
    }
]

my_layout = Layout(title="Global Earthquakes",margin={"l":0,"r":0,"t":0,"b":0})

fig = {"data": data, "layout": my_layout}

offline.plot(fig, filename='global_earthquakes.html')
```

Comment: Thanks, rob for the help but I don't want to use Plotly express bcoz it wants me to install pandas packages that I don't want now, so please suggest me another way to do it and here is my code, please do check them if it's correct or not let me know. Thanks again

Comment: I've updated answer,  very small tweaks to your setup code.  I don't have access to your file system ....  so get data directly using **requests**

Comment: Thank you so much, Rob for your time and help. I really appreciate it.